# How to reduce time complexity of a program that loops huge number of times?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to code (whole day)number generation system, it starts with 3 and the value decreases by 1 until it reaches 1. Once it reaches 1, it resets its number to a new starting value 2x as that of the first number. And then with each new reset 2x as the first number of the earlier reset. Like shown in bellow,

***3 2 1 6 5 4 3 2 1 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1...***

The program should **return the value of the nth position** that user request.

***user can enter n < (10^12)***

Tried skipping some steps if the target position is far away from the current position of the loop

```py
# requesting position
tt = int(input())
# starting t 
t = 1
# starting value
sv = 3
# current value
cv = 3

while (True):

    # check if we have reached target time
    if (t == tt):
        # print the current value
        print("{}".format(cv))
        break

    # if there's a loong way to go, skip some 
    if (t + cv < tt):  # starting_t+current_value<target_t
        t += cv  
        sv = sv * 2  
        cv = sv  

        if cv % 2 == 0:
            if (t + cv // 2 < tt):
                t += cv // 2
                cv = cv // 2
                continue
        continue

    # check if value is 1 and double it
    if (cv == 1):
        # set new starting value
        sv = sv * 2
        # set new current value
        cv = sv
        # elapse time
        t += 1
        continue

    # elapsed time
    t += 1
    # changed value
    cv -= 1
```

Currently, this program takes more than 2 minutes to return the result for ***n>10^10***. I need to reduce the time taken for the process as much as possible. What can I do to reduce the time taken for the process? (expect to reduce it to a couple of seconds) any reference may be helpful

Comment: What is your exit point? It looks like the problem could be solved analytically. Unless you need to be doing something at each iteration (in which case Cython / Numba / PyPy may be the way to go), I would advise you to work out the analytical expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

You can just do (indexing starts from `0`, otherwise you need to replace `n` with `n - 1`):

```
def my_seq(n):
    k = int(math.log2(n / 3 + 1)) + 1
    return 3 * (2 ** k - 1) - n


print([my_seq(i) for i in range(2)])
# [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21]
```

which is basically a variation of a geometric series with step equal 2, as shown below.

---

## Explanation

The first step is to notice that your underlying sequence of the "peaks" is a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression):

```
x_k = a * r ** k
```

The sum of the first n terms of a geometric progression is the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

```
sum(x_k for k in 1 to n) = a * (1 - r ** n) / (1 - r)
```

The target sequence is basically obtained by subtracting the index from the largest term of the series not exceeding the index itself.

In code, this looks like:

```
# note that this uses integer division hence expects integer `r`
def geom_series_int(a, r, n):
    return a * (1 - r ** n) // (1 - r)


def my_seq_int(n, a=3, r=2): 
    i = 1
    cumsum = geom_series_int(a, r, i) 
    while cumsum < n + 1:
        i += 1
        cumsum = geom_series_int(a, r, i)
    return cumsum - n


print([my_seq_int(i) for i in range(25)])
# [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21]
```

---

One could also compute the geometric series iteratively, of course, and this would be computationally of similar efficiency as the above code, due to the fact that finding the minimum `cumsum` not exceeding the index `n` is done with a loop, but the code from above is faster:

```
def i_geom_progression(a, r): 
    i = 0 
    while True: 
        yield a * r ** i 
        i += 1


def i_geom_series(a, r):
    gp = i_geom_progression(a, r)
    result = next(gp)
    while True:
        yield result
        result += next(gp)


def my_seq(n, a=3, r=2): 
    gs = i_geom_series(a, r) 
    cumsum = next(gs) 
    while cumsum < n + 1:
        cumsum = next(gs)
    return cumsum - n


print([my_seq(i) for i in range(25)])
# [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21]
```

The computational complexity in both cases is `log(n)`.

---

A more efficient approach is to do this analytically by solving for `k` the expression for the geometric series and using the index `n` as a proxy for the cumulative sum:

```
n = a * (r ** k - 1) / (r - 1)
```

becomes:

```
k = log_r(1 - n * (1 - r) / a)
```

and taking the integral part, this becomes:

```
import math


def my_seq_analytic(n, a=3, r=2):
    k = int(math.log2(1 - n * (1 - r) / a) / math.log2(r)) + 1
    return geom_series_int(a, r, k) - n


print([my_seq_analytic(i) for i in range(25)])
# [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21]
```

**This is the fastest approach.**

---

In general, the proposed methods are quite much faster than the method originally proposed, a simplification of which is reported in `my_seq_loop()` below:

```
def my_seq_loop(n, a=3, r=2):
    peak = a
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if a == 1:
            peak *= r
            a = peak
        else:
            a -= 1
    return a


print([my_seq_loop(i) for i in range(25)])
# [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21]
```

The give some idea of the timings, see the benchmarks below:

```
%timeit my_seq_loop(10 ** 8)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 6.65 s per loop
%timeit my_seq(10 ** 8)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop
%timeit my_seq_int(10 ** 8)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop
%timeit my_seq_analytic(10 ** 8)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 938 ns per loop
```

(EDITED to fix a bug in the code for analytics where integer division was used instead of regular division).

Comment: To get the right exponent you don't need to try them all. You can solve for m in a * (1 - r ** m) // (1 - r) < n by taking logarithm. m <= log_r ((r-1)n//a + 1).

Comment: @conditionalMethod Yes, sure. I was just writing up the math and code for it.

Comment: Note that is is assumed that indexing starts from `0` as it is customary in Python. Hence, `0` -> `3`, `1` -> `2`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute your answer without any loop :

After `n` resets, your number is `3*2^n`. Therefore, you have done 3*(2^{n}-1) steps.

So, if the user inputs the number `x`, you need to find how many resets you have done so far (which is the integer value of `log_2(x/3)`), let's call `R` this number, and find how many more steps you have performed since this reset, let's call this number `S`.

Then your solution is `3*(2^{R}-1) - S`.

Check on simple examples that this work, I may have made a mstake in my maths, but the method should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do:

```
def get_n_th_number(x, n):
    if n <= x:
        return x - n + 1

    return get_n_th_number(2 * x, n - x)

x = 3

assert get_n_th_number(x, 1) == 3
assert get_n_th_number(x, 3) == 1
assert get_n_th_number(x, 4) == 6
assert get_n_th_number(x, 9) == 1
assert get_n_th_number(x, 10) == 12
```

Time Complexity: `log2(n / x)`

Space Complexity: `log2(n / x)`  (Due to recursion.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved analytically without iterating through numbers and calculations as mentioned above. Finally able to solve the problem(of course with the help)

```
import math

def get_n_th(t):
    a=math.log((t/3)+1,2)   #if you input t,you need to get how many resets have done == integer value of log((t/3)+1, 2)
    # it always returns value > 0, even for the first reset (which is n need to be equal to zero) so we have to round number to least significant figures to get the correct reset value and substract 1 reset to get actual reset count

    # (3,2,1),   (6,5,4,3,2,1),  (12,11,10...)
    #    ^            ^               ^
    # 0th reset    1st reset       2nd reset
    #Bellow condition used to round number to least significant figures and sustract 1 reset. For further clarification please refer how log_2(n) return value and mentioned theory in the answer

    if(a%1 == 0):
        n = int(a-1)    # here n is equals to how many resets
        print("if")
    else:
        n = int(a)
    #here n gives how many resets occured
    #3*2**n will give the starting number of the last reset ---(1)
    #(t-3*(2**n-1))-1) will return how many steps remaining ---(2)
    # the difference between (1)-(2) will give the value in t position
    return (3*2**n)-((t-3*(2**n-1))-1)
    #or simplified equation
    #return 3 * 2 ** (n + 1) - t - 2


input = int(input())   #input the position
print(get_n_th(input))
print("[*] Ended in %.3f seconds." % (time.time() - start_time))
```

For understand this code you MUST refered **this [theory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286976/8388057) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287772/8388057)**. And also need to know the behaviour of **log_2(n)**.

Comment: This code has various points of improvement: there are a number of unused names (e.g. `count`), some of the variables are (or could) be used only once (e.g. `power_a`, `a`, `n`), some computations are redundant (e.g. `step = int(...)`, `steps_needed = int(...)`, etc.).

Comment: @norok2 Thank you!, I think I fixed them correctly after you mentioning them of course, so be kind to have a look and if it needs further modification, feel free to do or mention about it. Cheers!

Comment: This `((3*2**n)-((t-3*(2**n-1))-1))` can be written as: `3 * 2 ** (n + 1) - t - 2` and you could probably fix some other issues here and there. But most importantly, you get wrong results now. For `t == 2` you get `8`. Also, you provide no explanation for what you coded.

Comment: The wrong result was due to the **round()** function. I fixed it, normal rounding function cannot give the correct value for this program. And commenting was done(tried my best). To understand the code first need to understand the **geometric series** and how **log_2() behave**. Hope the reader understand it.Thanks for the guidance. :)

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. The code seems clunky.  Compare it with the answer you link. There the solution is written much more tersely, in 2 lines, as a (pure) function. Also, some of the comments are close to useless -- just restating what the code is doing instead of explaining why is not really helpful.

Comment: Also, the `if` part is useless. Just use `a = int(math.log(((t-1)/3)+1,2))` instead. And then it will be (if you use the rewriting in the last comment) essentially the same as the other answer.

Comment: @Idea O. Answer I linked indeed an excellent code, that is why I linked it. But it returns the geometric series, that wasn't the question. Question ask for **nth** value. And recommended to use `a = int(math.log(((t-1)/3)+1,2))` but it does **not work** for this program because the **a** need to round to least significant figures, I cannot describe it properly by comments it's the trickiest part of the code.Btw feel ashamed about that:(. I add more clarification to my code.

Comment: And @Idea O. I linked it, to get idea about the series. Btw the **input varies from 1 to 10^12** means the code takes hell of a time. So need to focus about the theory mentioned(analytical expression).

Comment: @Idea O. Damn, feel ashamed of me. Now I got it. All the time I was being dumb to focus on the iteration that was placed to show the series in that answer. Yeah you're right it is the perfect answer. I'm really sorry !

Comment: I did not realize you were the same person asking the question. Perhaps you should have asked @norok2 for some more explanation. I am sure s/he noticed all this.Anyway,glad I was of help.Cheers mate!

Comment: Thanks to him I was able to solve it. :) Cheers mate!